# Furnace wont stay lit

Tags: heating, furnace

My furnace is short cycling very quickly after ignition.  I put in a new flame sensor after cleaning the old one.
Then I checked each limit switch and all are closed and have continuity.
I checked the fan pressure switch and tube. It is also working and makes continuity.  The igniter glows bright. Gas comes on with a click. Flame bursts in chamber and immediately dies.
The circuit board has one light on steady.
Both fans are working.  But the flame immediately goes out.
New board, gas valve, pressure switch, and high limit switch last year. Seems like I've eliminated every viable source of what would cause the problem.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Check the air inlet - you may not be getting enough air flow for combustion. Had that problem a few weeks ago - a few old leaves had somehow managed to get in the air intake and were impacting air flow. Will need to beef up the protections on the air intake.

Comment: Is the a non-functioning condensate pump with a hardwired kill switch? How's the gas pressure?

Comment: Brand/model of your furnace? Also, don't ever post your phone number on the internet unless you're looking for tons of spam calls...

Comment: There's an operational sequence in the manual. Figure out which step it is stopping on and it should have troubleshooting steps for that step.